# Is it possible to make a form on one page and have it post to a different domain?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, cross-domain

I have been thinking for a while. And i have an idea i would like to have a sanity check on. The idea is this. I have a website www.mysite.com and you have a website www.yoursite.com I have a service on my site where you can "buy" a contact form (name, mail description) to your site. The trick is that it is still hosted on my page and i have the database the maintenance etc. but you have the functionality of a contact form on your page. Is this possible? How about an iFrame? Javascript? X-domain rules etc.

Will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other information that might be helpful from a nearly identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736647/submitting-a-form-to-another-server-do-i-need-an-api/5736713#5736713) posted today.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. There is no limit to where a form can point.

The only thing to be careful with is switching protocols.

- When you submit from a HTTPS form to a HTTP target, you will get a warning in some browsers.
- When it's the other way round, the `HTTP_REFERER` will not be set, so you can't use that to determine the incoming page. (But you will want to use a form variable for that anyway.)

Comment: It was my understanding that `HTTP_REFERER` should never be trusted?

Comment: @Madmartigan it indeed shouldn't, but in this case, he will have to trust either `HTTP_REFERER`  or a form variable, both of which can be manipulated with equal ease. He may need to check the referer to prevent misuse

Comment: I think that this is browser dependent as well, some do not even set HTTP_REFERER. In fact I've had Google Chrome send `favicon.ico` as the referer many times from my sites.

Comment: @Mad I'm not aware of a major browser that does not send HTTP_REFERER. It's still *fairly* reliable (but of course not 100%, and completely maniplable)